# Magento 2.3: problem understanding store views

Tags: magento2, store-view

I am having problems in understanding the Magento 2 store views.
We have used the default settings in Admin -> STORES -> Settings -> All Stores

We are only using one store view. However, I have not set Magento in Single Store Mode.

Working on a product in "Store View: All Store Views", means all values used here, are default values.  For instance, this means that if I change a product image on that page, that specific image is changed on other store views as well.

However, on the front end, the product images of the Default Store View appear.

In what Store View should I make the changes in order to have the products appear the same in all views?

[image: Magento 2 Stores]